# How to implement simple C++ function

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio

The programming challenge I am trying to solve is states as: write a function that accepts three arguments: **an array**, the **size of the
array**, and a **number n**. Assume that the array contains integers. The function should display all of the numbers in the array that are greater than the number n.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
void largerThanN(int a[], int size, int n);
int main()
{
    int size   = 3, 
    n      = 1, 
    arr[3] = { 0,5,6 };
    largerThanN(arr, size, n);
}

void largerThanN(int a[], int size, int n) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    {
        if (a[i] > n) 
        {
            cout << a[size] << " is greater than n " << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I have convoluted so far but I don't know if this is even remotely close to solving the challenge, maybe some direction from pro C++ devs would help out.

EDIT: I've figured it out with some help from you guys in the comments, thank you guys for helping a newbie out.  it means a lot.

Comment: `stdafx.h` is a non-standard header. SO is not a do-my-homework service. Read [more](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) about C++, use its standard [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container). Compile with all warnings and debug info, and use the debugger. The signature of `largerThanN` is wrong, that function should give a `bool` or maybe a `void` (and then it is badly named)

Comment: @OP Why are you accepting user-input with `cin`? From the problem description the int[] array (which you have not named in `largerThanN`) should contain all values you are meant to test against

Comment: You might want to grab a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465).

Comment: Maybe you should learn to read and understand a simple text before trying to implement it.

Comment: Rather than using a C-style array and having to pass the size, any sane person would instead use a [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (or a [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) if the size is known at compile time).

Comment: @manni66 i'm fully coherent that I don't understand c++ fully yet, i dont understand why you have to be so toxic about it.

Comment: You don’t have a problem with C++, you have a problem with reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this-

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void largerThanN(int[], int size, int n);

int main()
{
    int size;
    cin >> size;
    int a[size];
    for(int i=0; i < size; i++)
        cin >> a[i];
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    largerThanN(a, size, n);
    return 0;
}

void largerThanN(int a[], int size, int n)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if(a[i] > n)
            cout << a[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I hacked at it a little bit more and had the same exact thing for the function, but what you did in main() really helped me fully understand how to pass values to functions.  thank you @arnab

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
double largerThanN(int[], int size, int n);

int main() {
    int arr_size;    // array size
    cin >> arr_size;
    vector<int> arr(n);
    cout << "Enter values: ";
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        cin >> arr[i];
    int n;
    cin >> n;       // the no. to search for
    largerThanN(arr, arr_size, n);
    return 0; }

void largerThanN(int[], int size, int n) {
    int index;
    for (index = 0; index < size; index++) 
    {
        if (values[index] > n)
            cout << values[n] << endl;
    } }
```